# Update manifest version 2 have error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This is my  chrome extension,i have update manifest 2 but i don't know error,all function not working now

```
{
    "background": "background.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/urlchecker.png",
        "default_title": "All file hosting,folder in Page checker"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
            "js": ["urlchecker.js"],
            "matches": ["http://urlchecker.org/"]
        }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "images/*.png",
        "urlchecker.js",
        "core.js"
    ],
    "description": "Check the status of download links from various file hosts for free.",
    "icons": {
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
    },
    "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDvZzP2vIKjLBJq4ZnsHL8YN37WiVfm5gKtw5aJxVi9ADCVqbbSj9kXnBPqu3wYzfsf9DDOqp/kW/jsX1vErP5BpybRyebyc2lUfiFMc7YU7Qf2IS04wTAY3EWOfGoLIyNOiX1en91zGFywyd25VbWgWQ8GI3FPnpXY7RJbBPGuMQIDAQAB",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "UrlChecker",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs", "http://urlchecker.org/"],
    "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "version": "0.24"
}
```

and

urlchecker.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({command: "getLinks"}, function(response) {

//load the links in the box and click check button

    if (response.data.length > 0)
    {
        var txtLinks = document.getElementsByName("links")[0];
        var submit = txtLinks.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling;

        txtLinks.value = response.data;
        submit.click();
    }
});
```

Core.js

```
var links = "";
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(
        function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.create({
                'url': 'http://urlchecker.org/?url=' + tab.url,
                'selected': true
            }, function() {
            });
        });

function onClick(info, tab) {
    console.log("Running insode of addListener()");

    var tab = chrome.tabs.create({
        'url': "http://urlchecker.org/",
        'selected': true
    }, function() {
    });
    var data = JSON.stringify(info);
    if (info.selectionText == null) {
        links = info.linkUrl;
    }
    else {
        links = info.selectionText;
    }
}
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Selected Urls Checker",
    "contexts": ["link", "selection"],
    "onclick": onClick
});


chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
            if (request.command == "getLinks")
            {
                sendResponse({data: links});
                links = "";
            }
            else
                sendResponse({}); // snub them.
        });
```

and background.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Url checker!</title>
        <script src="core.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and zip all file

> https://www.mediafire.com/?vfl1t7u2bjta3am

Comment: Try to remove this line `"js": ["core.js"],`. you already have declared js with the previous line in your manifest file.

Comment: i removed but still error

Comment: Read the docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2

Answer (score 1):

```
 {
   "background": "background.html",
   ...
 }
```

Now with manifest version 2 it's:

```
 {
   "background": {
       "page" : "background.html"
   },
   ...
 }
```

or in your case you can remove the html and set directly

```
 {
   "background": {
       "scripts": ["core.js"]
   },
   ...
 }
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages